# Aumentar el valor de una casilla de una tabla sumando una variable dentro del código

Tags: php, sql, web

Tengo una tabla llamada Carrito, en la que se agregan productos mediante un catálogo de estos. Cada producto tiene su boton que manda el ID del producto ('Carrito-ProductoID').

Puedes agregar más de un producto, la primera vez utiliza el INSERT, y a partir de ahí, si se presiona de nuevo el boton del mismo producto, el código verifica si ya existe ese producto en la tabla y en ese caso utiliza un UPDATE. Las sentencias de Insert y Update sí funcionan, ya que lo intenté cambiando la variable de ('Cantidad EX') por un valor fijo.

El problema está en que al parecer el select siempre regresa el valor de 1, y el resultado siempre es 2.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $ProductoExistente = $_POST['Carrito-ProductoID'];

    $Consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT Cantidad FROM carrito WHERE ProductoID = :Producto AND CuentaID = ('0') LIMIT 1");

    $Consulta->execute(array(':Producto' => $ProductoExistente,));

    $Resultado = $Consulta->fetch();

    if($Resultado >0){
        
        $CantidadCarrito = intval($Resultado) + 1;

        $Accion = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE carrito SET Cantidad = :CantidadEX WHERE ProductoID = :ProductoIDC AND CuentaID = ('0')");
        $Accion->execute(array(':ProductoIDC' => $ProductoExistente, ':CantidadEX' => $CantidadCarrito));
    }else{
        $Accion = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO carrito (CarritoID, CuentaID, ProductoID, Cantidad) VALUES (null, 0, :ProductoIDC, 1)");
        $Accion->execute(array(':ProductoIDC' => $ProductoExistente));
    }
        
}
```

Al momento de dar click al boton de agregar no sale ningun error, ya intenté con Echos para leer el resultado, y siempre es 2, no hace la suma.
Muchas gracias por leer, y apreciaría mucho la ayuda, ya no se me ocurre mucho :c

Comment: Diría que tenes 2 errores: 
- `if($Resultado >0){` debería ser `if($Resultado !== false){`
- `intval($Resultado)` debería ser algo como `intval($Resultado['Cantidad'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos.**

Te sugiero extraer cada SQL; así verificar el resultado que te devuelve, algo así como una **Prueba de escritorio** para cerciorarte de los valores que obtiene en tu consulta y los que obtienes del resultado de la misma (por ejemplo en el `$Resultado = $Consulta->fetch();` veas que valor traes -cuando ya existe-).

Toda vez que por el momento **siempre** incrementas en 1; te sugiero actualizar tu SQL actual:

```
UPDATE carrito SET Cantidad = :CantidadEX WHERE ProductoID = :ProductoIDC AND CuentaID = ('0')
```

por

```
UPDATE carrito SET Cantidad = (Cantidad  + 1) WHERE ProductoID = :ProductoIDC AND CuentaID = ('0')
```

Con el cambio que te sugiero debes quedar dentro de tu `if($Resultado >0)` al ser verdadero

```
$Accion = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE carrito SET Cantidad = (Cantidad  + 1) WHERE ProductoID = :ProductoIDC AND CuentaID = ('0')");
$Accion->execute(array(':ProductoIDC' => $ProductoExistente));
```

Comment: Ya había intentado imprimir los resultados para revisar si cambian o no, y solo pasan las siguientes cosas

No hay producto
Haces click → No existe el producto → Agrega el producto con cantidad 1

Hay producto
Haces click → El producto existe → Lee la cantidad (1) y le suma 1 → Edita el campo de cantidad del producto al resultado (2)

Vuelves a hacer click → El producto existe → Lee la cantidad (2) y le suma 1 
Aquí parece que sí edita el resultado, pero el resultado sigue siendo 2 no importa cuantas veces le de click al mismo producto, el echo siempre imprime 2

Comment: @WoomySama saludos de nuevo. Me quede un poco atrás de PHP; la documentación de `fetch()` indica que retorna un array; no el valor de la columna `Cantidad`; puede ser por esto que siempre es 2 el valor que aplica al `UPDATE`. Prueba en lugar de `$CantidadCarrito = intval($Resultado) + 1;` que sea `$CantidadCarrito = intval($Resultado["Cantidad"]) + 1;`

Comment: Sisi, eso lo resolvió. Estaba checando lo que mandaba con var_dump y un profesor me dijo también lo del arreglo, así que solo lo cambié por esto

´$Resultado = $Consulta->fetch()['Cantidad'];´